# I cannot login after registration(while checking:echo num_rows() is 0 although having records)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter, I am trying to login after registration... I enter correct user name and password, but error is "No such account exists in database" which set message in `else` part if its false.

For checking I used `echo num_rows()` it's showing `0` (which is wrong), total 5 records are there but `echo num_fields` is showing 8 fields (which is correct).

**controller login code:**

```
public function login() {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'User Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('login');
    } else {
    //get user name
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    //get encrypt password
    $password = md5($this->input->post('password'));

    //login user
    $user_id = $this->auth_model->login($username, $password);
    if ($user_id) {
        //create session
        $user_data = array(
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'username' => $username,
            'logged_in' => true
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
        //set message
        $this->session->set_flashdata("success", "your are logged in");
        redirect('index.php/users/profile');
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("error", "No such account exists in database");
            redirect('index.php/auth/login');
        }
    }
}
```

**model login code:**

```
public function login($username, $password) {

    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);
    $result = $this->db->get('tblLogin');

    if ($result->num_rows() == 1) {
        return $result->row(0)->id;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use md5 on passwords!

Comment: thanq, yes i got it.. but how to encrypt passwords? no need of it encrypting password

Comment: Try this [tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/hashing-passwords-php-5-5-password-hashing-api/). Also did you try make that sql by your hand a check if it returns anything?

Comment: Please post your table structure and data type of `tblLogin`

Comment: - Table structure for table `tblLogin`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblLogin` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'id',
  `fullname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `phone` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `created_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UName` (`username`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=12 ;

Comment: In `tblLogin` inside stored password md5 or normal text?

Comment: am using md5...

Comment: Dont use md5 use this http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php to create password and use this callback to verify http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php md5 not secure any more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Controller:*

```
// log in user
    public function login() {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'User Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {


            $this->load->view('users/login');
        } else {
            //get user name
            $username = $this->input->post('username');

            //get encrypt password
            $password = $this->input->post('password');

            //login user
            $user_id = $this->auth_model->login($username, $password);
            if ($user_id) {
                //create session
                $user_data = array(
                    'user_id' => $user_id,
                    'username' => $username,
                    'logged_in' => true
                );

                $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
                //set message
                $this->session->set_flashdata("loggedin", "your are logged in");
                redirect('dashboard');
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata("log_failed", "Login invalid");
                redirect('login');
            }
        }
    }
```

*Model:*

```
public function login($username, $password) {

        $this->db->where('username', $username);

        $result = $this->db->get('tbllogin');

        $db_password = $result->row(0)->password;

        if (password_verify($password,$db_password)) {
            return $result->row(0)->id;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function login($username, $password) {

    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);
    $result = $this->db->get('tblLogin');
    $ret = $result->row();

    if ($ret) {
        return $ret;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

row() function get is single and check in if condition.
print your query using `$this->db->last_query();`
and check your mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution for your problem :

Changes your modal function:

> Modal.php

```
public function login($username, $password) {
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where('md5(password)', $password);
    $result = $this->db->get('tblLogin');
    $ret = $result->row();
    if (!empty($ret)) {
        return $ret;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Please changes your controller file.
    LoginController.php

```
public function login() {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'User Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('login');
    } else {
    //get user name
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    //get encrypt password
    $password = $this->input->post('password');

    //login user
    $user_id = $this->auth_model->login($username, $password);
    if ($user_id) {
        //create session
        $user_data = array(
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'username' => $username,
            'logged_in' => true
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
        //set message
        $this->session->set_flashdata("success", "your are logged in");
        redirect('index.php/users/profile');
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("error", "No such account exists in database");
            redirect('index.php/auth/login');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not working same error..if i remove md5 its executing